# how to store data in arabic in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, arabic

am using MySQL database, and i need to store data in Arabic into it, i have changed the collation to unicode so it works when am adding new fields through the PHPMyAdmin only, but when am adding data through my web site in to the same database it doesn`t works.

i need your help into this..

Answer (score 0):

Check that your website is using the same character encoding